# iOS Core Location Set Pin to user location in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, coordinates, core-location

I am attempting to set a map annotation to the user's current location. I am trying to set the pin in the viewDidLoad method, however because the method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Has not been called yet, the lat and long are 0.000000. Is there a way to call this method in my viewDidLoad  or any other solution that will make a pin appear at my beginning location when the application loads?

**UPDATE, Added Annotation Code**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
theCoordinate.latitude = (_currentLocation.latitude);
    theCoordinate.longitude = (_currentLocation.longitude);
    NSLog(@"The Coordinate Value:");
    NSLog(@"%f, %f",theCoordinate.latitude,theCoordinate.longitude);

    DDAnnotation *annotation = [[[DDAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
    annotation.title = @"Drag to Move Pin";
    annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

**UPDATE 2**
Still not working, code is in the didUpdateLocation Method

```
static BOOL annotationAdded = NO;

if (!annotationAdded) {
    annotationAdded = YES;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude = _currentLocation.latitude;
        theCoordinate.longitude = _currentLocation.longitude;
        //Sets Initial Point to Africa Because Method to obtain current Location
        //Hasen't Fired when View Loads
        theCoordinate.latitude = (mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude);
        theCoordinate.longitude = (mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        NSLog(@"The Coordinate Value:");
        NSLog(@"%f, %f",theCoordinate.latitude,theCoordinate.longitude);

        DDAnnotation *annotation = [[[DDAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
        annotation.title = @"Drag to Move Pin";
        annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude];

        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: still cant seem to get it to work properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MKMapView` automatically places an annotation of class `MKUserLocation` when you set `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES`.

You can replace the default view for this annotation to whatever default annotation view you want by doing this in `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        // replace the following with code to generate and return custom user position annotation view
        return customAnnotationView;
    }

    //*** other code ***//
}
```

***Update:***

If all you want to do is set a pin initially (once) at the user's location when the view loads, then you will have to wait until the phone can grab the data you need since that takes some time. Add your annotation in `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation` the first time it is called, and that should do the trick:

```
- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    static BOOL annotationAdded = NO;

    if (!annotationAdded) {
        annotationAdded = YES;
        //*** add annotation to mapView ***//
    }
}
```

***Final Comment:***

I would generally avoid setting a static pin at a users location the first time this method is called, however, and instead opt to just using the default standard blue dot. That is because the location services in the phone take time to find an accurate reading on the user's location, but in the interest of time it will send you location updates as soon as possible. This means that the first location update may not be very accurate, but subsequent updates may be much more accurate. That is why the standard blue dot sometimes changes position frequently within the first few moments of showing up on the map.

Just a caveat. Obviously what you choose to do depends on what the purpose of your app is.

Comment: I agree with all this, and will just point out that if the goal is to add a pin at the user's location as in @Matt's ***Update*** section, you can mitigate the concern from ***Final Comment*** by looking at the location's `horizontalAccuracy` property and waiting to add the annotation until the accuracy meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I've never found a way to manually call that method. I believe it's a delegate method that's completely passive. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time for the device to determine the location -- you can't speed up the process by calling -locationManager:didUpdateToLocation: yourself. You'll need to either use @Matt's suggestion to let the map draw the user's location, or else wait for -...didUpdateToLocation: to be called and take action then.

Comment: could you show code on how to wait for didUpdateLocation, then dropping the pin?

Comment: `-locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:` is a method that *you* implement in your location manager delegate. You don't need any special code, just take the code that you wanted to execute in `-viewDidLoad` and add it to `didUpdateToLocation:` instead. Or, put it in a separate method and call it from `didUpdateToLocation:`. You may want it to run only the first time you get a location rather than every time; if that's the case, use a flag to determine whether the code has run before.